# Issues with RegKey in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble with a Registry Key in Powershell.

The key /T/E/S/T gets generated by an unknown process:

[image: RegKey]

I then try to overwrite it using:

```
$Path = ".\setting\grouplocators"
$Name = "/T/E/S/T"
New-Item -Path $Path -Name $Name -Force
```

But it just creates a bunch of sub-folders

[image: Sub]

I have no issue when using cmd:

```
reg add ".\grouplocators\/T/E/S/T"
```

How can I get PowerShell to create the key with the name /T/E/S/T ?

Comment: use `Get-Item` or `Get-ItemProperty` to get the object as PoSh sees it. then use that to deal with the item.

Comment: Tried `Get-ItemProperty .\T\E\S\T` but it returns a `ObjectNotFound` error

Comment: i would  have tried `Get-Item` or `Get-ItemProperty` on the parent of that item. however, i see `mklement0` found the problem & you have a fix ... glad to know you got it! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to at least PowerShell 7.2.3, **PowerShell's registry provider** - unfortunately - **treats `\` and `/` *interchangeably* as path separators**, despite the fact that `/` is a legitimate character in a registry key's name - see [GitHub issue #5536](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5536).

As a result, it interprets a `/` as *separating two keys* instead of considering it a *part of a single key's name*.

**Workarounds**:

**To *create* a registry key with `/` in its name:**

Use the [`.CreateSubKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.createsubkey) .NET API, directly via the static properties of the  [`[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry) type that provide access to the various hives (.NET Framework 4+):

The following example creates a key in the `HKCU:` (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) hive, namely `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\temp\sub\A/B`:

```sh
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
  'temp\sub\A/B'
).Close()
```

- To target `HKLM:` / `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` instead - which requires *elevation* (running as admin) - use `[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.CreateSubKey()`
- Intermediate keys are created automatically, as needed - if the target key already exists, the call is a quiet no-op.
- The path *must not* start with `\`

---

**To *query* a registry key with `/` in its name:**

While you could similarly use .NET APIs to query such keys, there are workarounds if you want to stick with PowerShell cmdlets:

The most robust approach is to target the *parent* key with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and then filter by child key name with [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object):

```sh
Get-ChildItem HKCU:\temp\sub | Where-Object PSChildName -eq 'A/B'
```

- **Caveats**:

  - If key names *start with* `/` (as in your `/T/E/S/T` example):

    - The `.PSChildName` property value then unexpectedly contains the name *without the initial `/`* - so that you'd have to use the very same command as above to test for key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\temp\sub\/A/B`.
    - Using *wildcards* with the *parent* path (`HKCU:\temp\sub\*`) then malfunctions altogether (reports a spurious error about a nonexistent key), both with `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Item`.
  - Even with without an initial `/`, using wildcards with the parent path malfunctions with `Get-ChildItem` *when combined with `-Include`* (no output), but curiously not with `Get-Item`.

Curiously, however, [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path), *does* properly recognize `/` as part of the key name when testing the existence of a registry path:

```sh
Test-Path HKCU:\temp\sub\A/B    # OK: -> $true
```

- **Caveat**: If key names *start with* `/`, `Test-Path` does *not* find the key, and there is seemingly no way to make it work.